# Bitcoin mining for the regular person?

Tags: mining-theory, mining-profitability, mining-hardware, mining-reward

Is it feasible for a regular person to mine crypto like Bitcoin with just a couple of machines?  Or is the wear and tear to those machines coupled with the electricity costs just too much to make it a worthwhile endeavor?

Comment: This is the best article for miners who prefer to setup things at home:  https://www.econoalchemist.com/post/home-mining-for-non-kyc-bitcoin and it all depends on what you pay for electricity at the end of the day. In India there are places where you get free or subsidized electricity. Problem is nobody is as smart as China to make hardware or assemble or they think its scam.

Comment: And there are places which can provide electricity to one small city or village with few wind mills or solar cells. I recently visited one place in hills of Karnataka during my travel. But everything belongs to governments or few rich people now. Although same trend can be seen in Bitcoin.